# Problem with query as a new data source in Cognos PowerPlay

Tags: datasource, olap, cognos

Normally you can add a query as a new data source in Cognos PowerPlay (I'm running PowerPlay version 7.3), but when I try to do so I cannot select any queries from my Access database. The dropdown menu which normally shows the existing queries in the database is empty. When I add a table as a new data source it works fine, and all the tables are shown in the dropdown.

Previously it worked fine for queries too, but now it won't work.
Does anybody know if it's a Cognos error or some system configuration on my pc that causes this error to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any answers to my question, but I did come up with a workaround solution for this problem.

The trick is to create a new MS Access database (fx called WorkAroundDatabase) and then create a query that has the same name as the original query in the mother database (the name of the query you wanted to add as data source in the first place).

Then you first create a new data source that links to the query in the WorkAroundDatabase.
Secondly you right-click on the data source and change the path to the mother database. Since the names of the queries are the same the data source now links to the query in the mother database (which was what you wanted, byt couldn't do directly because of the Cognos Powerplay bug).

This procedure works just fine in Cognos PowerPlay, even though it doesn't give any explanations on the original error in Cognos PowerPlay.